# Keras, Improper Input Shape

Tags: python, image, keras, convolution

I am receiving an error about the dimensions of the input to my flatten layer.

`ValueError: The shape of the input to "Flatten" is not fully defined (got (0, 12, 10). Make sure to pass a complete "input_shape" or "batch_input_shape" argument to the first layer in your model.`

I am receiving this error because one of my dimensions is zero, correct? Trying to figure out why it is being reduced down to zero but not sure where this error is occurring.

I have been trying to calculate what the output should be after the convolutional layers, before the flatten layer. I can't get them to line up when compared with `model.summary()`.

I am not sure exactly how `model.summary()` output shape is formatted, is it None, width, length, depth?

The equation I used to calculate the output shape: `(width - filter_size + 2(padding)/shifting) + 1`

format: depth, width, height

first convolutional shape: 10, 14, 14
second convolutional shape: 10, 12, 12

can someone explain why the depth of first integer value is being reduced in the `model.summary()` output shape column below?

```

```
_________________________________________________________________
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)            (None, 2, 14, 10)         1450
_________________________________________________________________
activation_9 (Activation)    (None, 2, 14, 10)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)           (None, 0, 12, 10)         910
_________________________________________________________________
activation_10 (Activation)   (None, 0, 12, 10)         0
=================================================================
Total params: 2,360
Trainable params: 2,360
Non-trainable params: 0
```

```

It seems like the input shape was entered incorrectly in my Convolution2D layer but I have entered as the documentation suggests.

```

```
model = Sequential()

batch_size = 20
nb_epoch = 20

nb_filters = 10 
kernel_size = (3, 3)
input_shape = (4, 16, 16)
pool_size =(2, 2)

model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, (kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1]), input_shape=input_shape, kernel_initializer='TruncatedNormal'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, (kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1]), kernel_initializer='TruncatedNormal'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_size))
model.summary()

# model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(.3))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer='Adamax', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

```

Backend:Theano

Comment: This is the typical dimension ordering issue, you seem to have set dimension ordering to channels last, while the input shape you put is using channels first.

Comment: I was defaulted to ordering channels last so I changed that but now I am getting the error above look at my new edit. Why is the first value now 1182, which is batch size correct?

Comment: Now seems your input data has the wrong shape, it should be (1182, 16, 16, 4).

Comment: So I entered that value and received this error `ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_17: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5`

Comment: You did something wrong, because the shape I gave you is 4D, not 5D.

Comment: hmm... all I did was add the number of images to the dimension shape like you suggested.

Comment: That's not what I suggested. Your input data has channels first, while the input shape has the channels at the end of the shape sequence.

Comment: I am sorry misunderstood. So I need to keep my channel as first but change the keras.json "image_data_format" to "channels_first" correct?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro switching the image_data_formate worked. Great advise